# UWP Adjusting Grid and Other Tools Depending on Resolution

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, resolution

I am creating an app that is going to be put onto a tablet that has a 7 in screen and a resolution of 1280x800. However in the case that we use the app on tablets that have a higher or lower resolution, I would like the entire app to adjust to it accordingly. Is there a way to make my app and all the tools on the page adjust to the resolution of any screen?

Comment: What part do you want to adjust?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried VisualStateManager? Well, you can learn much about Universal Windows Platform at MVA

Here's the link : https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners-14541

Comment: So if I use this, it will adjust the app to the appropriate resolution of the tablet?

Comment: well, basically you have to define (like if else statement) for called resolution, how you want the view look like and change many parameter at every object in xaml you want to change (ex : button fontsize:24 in phone, fontsize:34 tablet, yeah something like this).

Comment: Now I noticed that this is a feature for app on Windows 10, but the tablet I am using is running Windows 8.1. Will it be able to run on that too?

Comment: The old windows 8.1 used different xaml file with shared resources. So i think not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AdaptiveTrigger to resize or change the layout of your views this feature is only for UWP apps 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/developers/articles/week03aug15/designing-with-adaptive-triggers-for-windows-10/

If you are using Windows 8.1 you have  3 projects  Windows 8.1(desktop) Windows phone 8.1(Phone) and shared.

You need to create a specific view for each platform with your custom layout .

Maybe if you need to detect the resolution and effective pixels to do something special

```
var bounds = Window.Current.Bounds;
```

double height = bounds.Height;

double width = bounds.Width;

With this information can modify your controls depending of the width or height of the screen.

Best Regards